# How to manage android classic bluetooth and bluetooth low energy connections simultaneously?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have two classic bluetooth and one bluetooth low energy connections to manage. I have connected these bluetooth devices to 3 different lights.

I am creating two different socket for  classic bluetooth connections and keeping them on different threads. I am simultaneously sending commands to these devices. My problem is if I am connecting to the BLE device first, there will be no delay in receiving commands. But when I am connecting classic bluetooth devices first, BLE device shows delay in responding to the commands.

I have to send commands to these 3 bluetooth devices simultaneously, but only classic bluetooth works without latency. BLE seems to be very slow responding to commands if it is operated with classic bluetooth connections.